# Arch boot WARNING: pci DPC: RP PIO log size 0 is invalid

Tags: linux, arch-linux, boot, systemd-boot

I installed Arch on my new Dell 9300 following this guide: https://github.com/Spissable/arch-linux-installation/blob/master/README.md

Everything works fine, I can boot into my system. But there are two warnings when booting that popup before the normal systemd-boot output:

```
pci 0000:00:07.0: DPC: RP PIO log size 0 is invalid
pci 0000:00:07.2: DPC: RP PIO log size 0 is invalid
```

The only thing I could find to this was: https://www.spinics.net/lists/kernel/msg3763759.html
I did a BIOS check and all hardware components are fine.

Any ideas to why this could happen?

Comment: Did you figure this out? I have the same warning in my Dell XPS 9300. Does this help: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=209943 - it's because it's outside of specs for the USB 4. I would assume nothing to worry about, should be really a info message not error.

Comment: By the way, do you see the `can't query Synaptics device -1` message as well?

Comment: Same issue, occasionally on Lenovo Yoga

Answer (score 1):

It was a kernel bug, that recently got a working patch. You can use that or wait for the next kernel release.

See https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=209943

Comment: Can approve, bug got fixed with the patch.